# Не работает простейший Hello Word

Tags: kotlin

Я принялся за изучение котлин и столкнулся с проблемой что он не выводит простейший Hello Word:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

Выводит

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=59825:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-compiler.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-reflect.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-script-runtime.jar" org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler -kotlin-home "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -script C:/Users/freQuensy/IdeaProjects/untitled/main.kts
main.kts:1:10: warning: parameter 'args' is never used
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
         ^

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Удалил аргументы (то что в скобках у main) Теперь просто возвращает пустую консоль. Использую `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 x64`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть два подхода убрать это предупреждение:
 - сменить расширение вашего файла с `.kts` на `.kt`.
 - оставить расширение, но добавить непосредственный вызов функции `main` из кода скрипта, а сам массив `args` использовать каким-то образом:

```
main(arrayOf<String>("hello from script"))

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(args[0])
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

`.kts` - это Котлин скрипт, который просто исполняется сверху вниз, как, например, `bash` скрипт, и функция `main` для него не является точкой входа.

`.kt` - это Котлин класс, и он будет работать таким же образом, как любой Java класс, то есть искать и начинать выполнение с метода `main`, подставляя в массив `args` переданные при запуске программы аргументы.

Comment: `у вас функция main не вызывается непосредствено никаким другим кодом, поэтому компилятор и выдаёт предупреждение, что входящий параметр args нигде не используется` - параметр args в этом коде в любом случае не используется, предупреждение выдается не из-за того что main не вызывается.

Comment: @insolor понял о чём вы, проапдейтил с примером того, как args можно использовать принудительно. Врядли автор хотел именно это, но для полноты картины может пригодиться.